# Gmail does not allow margin property

Tags: html, css, gmail, newsletter

I want apply margin property for my html newsletter

But Gmail ignores this CSS property

Is there any way to add margin to html element ?

Thanks

Comment: There are a lot of mail clients to check against - you might be better off using something like Mailchimp.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With HTML email you need to go back to the dark ages and use tables. Sad but true.

[Rock Solid HTML Emails](http://24ways.org/2009/rock-solid-html-emails) will help you.

Answer (score 2):

Tables are the best things you can use for newsletters. Also remember that if are you using CSS it's better if you do it inline. In other words, like this:

```
<table style="margin: 0 0 15px 50px; color: #FFFFFF;"></table>
```

Do not have CSS in the header.

Answer (score 2):

Yes @Alex is right when he says use in-line CSS. One thing though, No CSS shorthand is used: instead of using the abbreviated style rule `margin:0 0 15px 50px` use `margin-top:0; margin-right:0; margin-bottom:15px; margin-left:50px;`

Check http://www.sitepoint.com/code-html-email-newsletters/

Answer (score 0):

As of 8/30/2022 Gmail supports the margin style property.

see https://developers.google.com/gmail/design/reference/supported_css

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).